# How to share classes from containing app in Today extension ?

Tags: swift, today-extension

After Throwing an error of unresolved identifier of main app class in Today view controller, I tried to checkmark the widget target of all the classes in the main app. Still, getting pod errors(MBprogresHUD no member).
Is there any simple way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

create separate target for share extension in pod file and specify the pods name that you want to install.

for example:
your pod file should be as follows, here
ProjectName is your project target name
ShareExtensionName is your share extension target name

platform :ios, ‘9.0’

use_frameworks!

def general_pods

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

end

target ‘ProjectName’ do

```
general_pods
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

end

target ‘ShareExtensionName’ do

```
general_pods
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
```

end

Comment: Thanks! I Forgot to include MBProgressHUD custom class.